# Vacuum Full calibration for production context.(reorganize subjects identification)

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, reorganize

My aim is to calibrate vacuum full usage within production context,
knowing that vacuum full locks exclusively objects that I need to maintain.

- how should I identify only the list of objects where the vacuum full is worth it?
- How do I convert dead tuples to space consumption? and so estimate reclaimed space and decide.
- Should I refresh statistics before using dead tuples inf ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `VACUUM (FULL)` as part of your regular maintenance. If you cannot find a way to avoid that, have a look at [pg_squeeze](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze).

Comment: total agree it is not a part of regular maitenance, basides we have application with no downtime, so we will need it, thanks for sharing pg_squeeze (btw what is the difference with pg_repack used by rds amazon?)

Comment: pg_squeeze is better.